# Display a single pushpin when two or more pushpins are located at same geo-location n Bing V8 Maps

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

Is there any possibility of displaying a single pushpin when two or more pushpins are located at same geo-location in Bing V8 Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the common way of handling this is through clustering. Bing Maps has a clustering module that is built in. This module groups pushpins that are close together into a cluster pushpin which is a single pushpin that links to the individual pushpin information. As you zoom the map the clusters will form and break apart. Here are some samples and resources:

http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Clustering_Basic

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712807.aspx